# Portable Home Directory without OS X server

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, network-shares

I have a Mac Mini and two MacBook Pros.  I would like to have documents shared between the two MPBs and backed up to the Mac Mini (where I have time machine running backing up the files to an external disk).  Most of the time the MBPs will be connected to the same network as the Mini, but occasionally we'll take them out and want to have all of the documents local to the MBP.

It looks like Portable Home Directories are what I want, but the Mini is not running OS X Server.  Is it possible to get PHDs working without upgrading the Mini to Server?  I guess I'll need to install an LDAP server on the Mini, but I'm not sure what else I may need.

As a side note, I've currently just got two rysnc cron jobs running on the MPBs to do a two way sync between the MBP and the Mini, but obviously this won't cope with file renames/deletes.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: [Portable Home Directory over NFS on OSX authenticated via OpenLDAP on Debian Linux](http://mattfleming.com/node/190)

The LDAP server is running on Linux, but you could easily install the service on your Mac mini and configure it more or less identically.